# How to load & save PVR images using C#

Tags: c#, pvrtc

I'm making a tool which would be able to load and save .PVR images using C#. Searched the internet but found nothing. Do you have any ideas? Or is there any format specification?

Answer (score 2):

There is C/C++ code available somewhere (but I can't remember where it was located - sorry) but the PVR file format appears to be documented in the Imagination Technologies' "PVRTexLib Library" package ([linked from here](http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/powervr-utilities.asp)) which can be obtained with a free registration.